# Angular: /deep/ doesn't work on angular upgrade

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular6, angular-cli, ng-deep

I have my application in angular5 and I upgraded it to angular6. I have my scss files with /deep/ to override the styles. All the styles with it is broken now. I tried ::ng-deep/ng:host::ng-deep didn't work. I tried keeping viewEncapsulation but that didn't work either. So I am trying to see what can be done.

Comment: you said tried it like this: `:host /deep/ .some-class { }`

Comment: @NadhirFalta I tried ::ng-deep and :ng-host::ng-deep. I didn't try :host /deep/

Comment: try that it should work

Comment: @NadhirFalta It is throwing an error.         :host /deep/ .mat-radio-label {
             ^
      Expected selector. Should I keep viewEncapsulation.None ?

Comment: you need space between :host and /deep/ and class anme

Comment: @NadhirFalta Even after keeping encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None, it is still throwing { ^ Expected selector. error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229702/discussion-between-indra257-and-nadhir-falta).